# create a generalized function to transpose the columns and make dictionaries as values in the other column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this spark data frame. I am trying to convert the columns to rows and make one of the columns gw are the key of the dictionary in the other column. I want to write a generalized function for this which can take multiple columns as input.

```
+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|  gw |rrc |re_est|
+-----+-------------------+
|  210.142.27.137  |  1400.0|  26.0|  
|   210.142.27.202|  2300|  12 |
```

expected output like this:

```
+-----+-----------+-
| index    |gw_mapping|
+-----+------
|  rrc  | {210.142.27.137:1400.0, 210.142.27.202: 2300}|
|  re_est |  {10.142.27.137:26.0, 210.142.27.202:12 }|
```

What I have done:

```
result_df = (
df
.select('gw', F.expr("stack(2, 'rrc', rrc, 're_est', re_est)  AS (index, value)"))
.groupby('index')
.agg(F.expr("map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(gw, value))) as gw_mapping")))
```

I am unable to get the output somehow if I write a generalized function that can take multiple columns like rrc, re_est

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To genralize the solution you can create a dynamic stack expression

```
cols = ['rrc', 're_est']
expr = f"stack({len(cols)}, %s) AS (index, value)" % ', '.join(f"'{c}', {c}" for c in cols)
result_df = (
    df
    .select('gw', F.expr(expr))
    .groupBy('index')
    .agg(F.expr("map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(gw, value))) AS gw_mapping"))
)
```

---

```
result_df.show()

+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|index |gw_mapping                                          |
+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|re_est|{210.142.27.137 -> 26.0, 210.142.27.202 -> 12.0}    |
|rrc   |{210.142.27.137 -> 1400.0, 210.142.27.202 -> 2300.0}|
+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```