# Is there an efficient way to union all the spark dataframes than using union()?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to union a big spark data frame. But I am getting `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26434.collectToPython. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 390 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down`
Is there any better way to union the dataframes that will be efficient in terms of performance, especially when you are dealing with large DataFrames?
I am adding the error stack trace.  I have tried this code without using union()  well but it gave me the same error.

I am using spark version `3.1.0`

```
def get_misc_exception(df: DataFrame, grouping_columns: list, distribution_cols: list) -> DataFrame:
    misc_df = None
    misc_cols_df_list = []
    
    for key, value in misc_cols_dict.items(): 
        print(f'{key}----------------')
        
        filtered_df = df.filter(value)
        
        if filtered_df.rdd.isEmpty():
            data = [(data_date, hour, key, 0, 0, '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')]
            misc_col_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema = final_df_schema)
            
        else:
            misc_col_df = get_exception(filtered_df, grouping_columns, distribution_cols)
            misc_col_df = misc_col_df.withColumn('Exception', F.lit(key)).select(*final_df_cols)
                
        misc_cols_df_list.append(misc_col_df)
        
    misc_df = misc_cols_df_list[0]
    
    for misc_cols_df in misc_cols_df_list[1:]:
        misc_df = misc_df.union(misc_cols_df)
    
    return misc_df
```

Error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py in toPandas(self)
    136 
    137         # Below is toPandas without Arrow optimization.
--> 138         pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
    139         column_counter = Counter(self.columns)
    140 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    594         """
    595         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 596             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    597         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    598 

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    126     def deco(*a, **kw):
    127         try:
--> 128             return f(*a, **kw)
    129         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    130             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26434.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 390 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1(DAGScheduler.scala:979)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:977)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:2257)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2170)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$12(SparkContext.scala:1973)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1357)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1973)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anon$3.run(SparkContext.scala:1922)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2120)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2139)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2164)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3450)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3447)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the full java error stack trace? It should be multiple lines long and will be located underneath the python error.

Comment: @Koedlt added the error stack trace.

Comment: can you put in the code for get_exception method too ? Looks like you are doing somewhere conversion from spark df to pandas df which is trying to collect all the dataframe into 1 node and hence it's causing the issue. 
Don't think issue is with unioning.

Comment: Also if your dataframe is huge and you are using spark < 3.x, you should use `df.limit(1).rdd.isEmpty()` this will avoid your entire dataframe being converted into rdd which will be faster than converting the entire df to rdd.
In case you are using Spark 3.x, just go with `df.isEmpty()`

Comment: @Frosty  `Looks like you are doing somewhere conversion from spark df to pandas``->` I am doing conversion of the `misc_df` returned by `get_misc_exception`

Comment: @Frosty my spark version is `3.0.1`

Comment: Check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612622/spark-unionall-multiple-dataframes

Comment: @AfonsodePaulaFeliciano I have already tried the link you shared. `df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)` I got the same error.